# Join videos side by side

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv

In what way can I join these four videos side by side (with 10px margin between the left and the right side. No margin between top and bottom)?

- top_left.mp4
- top_right.mp4
- bottom_left.mp4
- bottom_right.mp4

Kdenlive is so buggy and drove me crazy. Any command line method is welcome.

Comment: see e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other. Or search for "ffmpeg side-by-side".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Video only

### 10px border between left & right

[image]

There are several methods to do this, but using [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack), [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack), and [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) is probably the easiest:

```
ffmpeg -i top_left.mp4 -i bottom_left.mp4 -i top_right.mp4 -i bottom_right.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]vstack,pad=iw+10:ih[l]; \
 [2:v][3:v]vstack[r]; \
 [l][r]hstack" \
output.mp4
```

- Inputs must be the same width, height, and "pixel format". If they are not use the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and/or [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filters to prepare the streams for the *stack filters.
- Use `*stack=shortest=1` if you want the filter output to terminate when the shortest input terminates.

### 10px border between left & right, 3px border between top & bottom

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i top_left.mp4 -i bottom_left.mp4 -i top_right.mp4 -i bottom_right.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw:ih+3[tl]; \
 [tl][1:v]vstack,pad=iw+10:ih[l]; \
 [2:v]pad=iw:ih+3[tr]; \
 [tr][3:v]vstack[r]; \
 [l][r]hstack" \
output.mp4
```

## With combined audio

The [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter will combine all input channels, then `-ac 2` will downmix them to stereo:

```
ffmpeg -i top_left.mp4 -i bottom_left.mp4 -i top_right.mp4 -i bottom_right.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]vstack,pad=iw+10:ih[l]; \
 [2:v][3:v]vstack[r]; \
 [l][r]hstack[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

- Using amerge, the combined audio will only be as long as the shortest input. If that is a problem then use [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix).

Comment: Thanks a lot.                                                     .